# How to set selectable, but not focusable one tab in TabLayout?

Tags: android

Like this..

```
mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setFocusable(false);
```

on TabLayout,

```
mTabLayout.setFocusable(boolean);
```

is working, 
but on one tab isn't

Answer (score 0):

you can change tab by index values of tabs

```
mTabLayout.getTabAt(someIndex).select();
```